# SQL Query content from XML issue

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

This is the XML table I need to query.
[image]
And I need to query the 52324672-bd54-44cf-b836-869d39d64bd8 from value tag.
I tried to query like this [image]
But it is not working as the issue looks from the i:type="a:string" and xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance".

Comment: When you say it is "not working", what exactly does that mean?  You're getting an error message?  You're getting an unexpected result?

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe you added a screenshot of the XML text. Next time, please copy and paste the XML directly. This will allow others to help you more effectively with your specific XML issue.

> But it is not working as the issue looks from the i:type="a:string" and xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance".

From the second screenshot, you have a different XML structure that does not include the namespace `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`. This namespace is required because there's a namespace on the child element value. To retrieve the value `523..`, here's an example xquery you can use:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<ArrayOfKeyValuePairOfstringanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType subsheetid="feb" type="xx" published="True">
        <key>3d65</key>
        <value xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="a:string">523</value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
</ArrayOfKeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
';

SELECT 
    c.value('(value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS [Value]
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfKeyValuePairOfstringanyType/KeyValuePairOfstringanyType[1]') AS t(c);
```

**Note:** The above script will return the value child element of `KeyValuePairOfstringanyType` due to the presence of the predicate [1]. If you have multiple `KeyValuePairOfstringanyType` parent elements and want to return all `value` for each `KeyValuePairOfstringanyType`, you'll need to remove the `[1]`. Basically, this is just one example. There are so many ways to shred XML.